# How can I generate a route in Laravel with a placeholder/replaceable value for use in JS at runtime?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I have a route that returns post data in JSON:

```
Route::get('posts/{post}/data', 'PostController@getData')->name('data.post');
```

which is called by JS in the front:

```
<a href="#" data-post-id="{{ $post->id }}" class="post-links">{{ $post->title }}</a>
```

The click is bound like this:

```
$(".post-links").click(function() {
    var postId = $(this).data('post-id');
    $.get( "{{ route('data.post') }}" + postId, function(data) {
        // process the data...
    });
});
```

The problem here is that this the URL for `get` has to be generated in the front-end depending on which link has been clicked, but Laravel has already processed the `route` method while rendering the view. Without an `id` parameter, the route generation fails. How do I get the route base with a parameter?

Comment: You know exactly how you URL will be rendered like this `posts/1/data`, you must put in your ajax request the url manually and instead of waiting laravel generate it for you, and after that you can change the ID that you get from the data-post-id attribute of you link,

Comment: @yvesdaxmaz That defeats the purpose of using dynamic route generation. If I change the URL route later to `/articles/approved/1/data`, then I'll have to change the paths in the JS files everywhere I'm using it.

Comment: when you are trigger the click event, you view are rendered and you must find same way to get the url that will handle you ajax request, and that URL  need a ID that are already in you html that are generate by laravel. when you HTML are generate you are in you client side of you application in this case precisely you are in you browser and when  view are rendered the single way for laravel to generate a new route is only when he will get a new request to handler, that is the reason why you must generate the url manualy

Comment: @yvesdaxmaz What?

Comment: Because laravel has already processed the 'route' method when rendering you `view template`, in you front you will have in your javascript code `$.get("http://..../posts/????/data)`  and you goal is to change the ID in that url automatically after click on same links. you must change that url `$.get("this url")` in code that are execute when the click event is fire. to do that you must get the ID from the data-post-id attribute and put it in your URL, that can't be done by laravel because view is already rendered

Comment: @yvesdaxmaz Yes and that is exactly what my main question above is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Js you can do something like this.

```
var postId = $(this).data('post-id');
var url = "{{ route('data.post', ':url') }}";
url = url.replace(':url', postId);
```

for multiple wild card

```
 var postId = $(this).data('post-id');
 var anotherId = 1;
 var url = "{{ route('test', [':url',':url1']) }}";
 url = url.replace(':url', postId);
 url = url.replace(':url1', anotherId);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is not a bad trick. I'll accept this for now, but I'll keep a look out for more solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that's less dependent on front-end code:

Set the route parameter to be optional:

```
Route::get('data/posts/{post?}', 'DataController@post')
    ->name('data.posts);
```

Now, you can easily call the base route and append the id in JS:

```
$(".post-links").click(function() {
    var postId = $(this).data('post-id');
    $.get( "{{ route('data.posts') }}/" + postId, function(data) {
        // process the data...
    });
});
```

So much neater than replacing strings!

This does have some pitfalls to avoid, namely that the optional parameter makes a route such as `/data/posts` a valid route, so you just have to handle that exception in case posts is `null`.

I believe this is a better solution, so I'll make this as the correct answer, but I like the other solution too.

*Update:* Considering the original question, which is about a placeholder or replaceable value, the other answer is factually correct. This answer of my own is an alternative to using a placeholder, so I'll mark the other answer as the correct one.

Comment: this wont work for the wildcards which are in between the routes.but if your requirement is fulfilled its great..:)

Comment: @Rohitshah Yeah, if the wildcards are in the middle of the route, then your method is the way to go.